# Programming a bot for Lotus Sametime: Are there any test server?

Tags: testing, lotus, sametime

I'm currently working on a chat-bot for IBM Lotus Sametime. I'm following this [tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/ls-ST_Bots1/index.html).

My problem is, that I don't know how to test my bot: I've got access to a Sametime server, but I only have my personal account. It's no problem to log the bot in with this username and password, but I can't test it, because I can only log in with the same account and the bot won't react.

My question is: What is the best way to test such a bot? Can anyone point me at a working public server where I can register two accounts? Am I missing something?

Thank you

Btw: I already tested http://bleedyellow.com/ and the link from this [tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/sametime-translation/#N100F5). They all seem to be unreachable or long since abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to test a bot, as with any software development exercise like this, is to do so on a test server, with a test account. bleedyellow.com is an active community, but it doesn't offer public test accounts. You'll need to set up a dev / test Sametime instance.